How to update struct which sored in map, tact language, ton

1 step - add structure to map - good, 2 step - read structure from map using get fun good, 3 step - when try to read structure from map in receive - crash
whats going wrong, or how to fix, or any examples for CRUD operations of structures in map through receive functions?
